# Implementing GL_REPEAT on shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, textures

I'm trying to implement GL_REPEAT on glsl. I wrote something using the mod function but there's a [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NQQh.png) where the two textures combine. Could you explain why it doesn't work right?

**in main:**

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

**my shader code looks like this:**

```
in vec2 TextureCoord;

float yCoord = mod(TextureCoord.y + 0.5, 1.0);
emission = texture(material.emission,vec2(TextureCoord.x, yCoord)).rgb;

//result
vec3 result = emission;
FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0f);
```

Comment: "*where the two textures combine*" You only have one texture, so what do you mean by that? Are you talking about the seam between the repetitions?

Comment: Did you set the texture border color?  The default value is black, which may be the source of the seam in the image your provide.  Perhaps try setting the border color to white (or whatever the background color is for that test image).

Comment: yes I'm talking about seam between the repetitions. I set border color to white but it still visible. if I change GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER to GL_REPEAT and emission = texture(material.emission,vec2(TextureCoord.x, TextureCoord.y + 0.5)).rgb the line in between is not visible.

Comment: When I select the border color white, the line is a little thinner but this time the line becomes thicker if I choose a black picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrap mode is honored during *texture filtering*. You set the `GL_LINEAR` filter mode, hence it will always use a `2x2` texel footprint. If that footprint happens to be at the border, the selected wrap mode will apply *to selecting each individual texel*. In your case, if you get near the border, you told it to filter into the textrue border color, which a filter with `GL_REPEAT` wrap mode never would have done, it would have used the texel data from the opposing border instead.

So *if* you want to re-implement that manually in the shader, you must also *implement the texel selection and the filtering itself*. Since you also use mipmapping, doing so will be quite complex, and slow.

Comment: I get what you're trying to say, but when I set the border color to white, the problem still persists (the black line becomes thinner but doesn't completely go away). Shouldn't' `GL_LINEAR` make the seam white when I set the border color to white because both border color and the texture color are the same color?

Comment: Nope. You do a wrap-around in such a way that you'll get texcoords close to 1.0 in one fragment and close to 0.0 in the neighboring fragment. That means you map the whole texture to the size of one pixel, which means it is a _minification_, and then you mipmap minification filter is applied. You cannot do it that way. You need to fetch indivudual texels in your shader, otherwise your discontinuity in the texcoords will screw up any sort fo `GL_LINEAR` filtering.